# PHP openssl_pkcs12_read "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, openssl

I'm getting the error `Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"` when trying to open a `.pfx` file:

```
$result = openssl_pkcs12_read($content, $certdata, $pass);
$error = openssl_error_string(); // "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"
```

In terminal (Ubuntu 22.04):

```
user@user-tp:~$ php -i | grep -i openssl
SSL Version => OpenSSL/3.0.2
libSSH Version => libssh/0.9.6/openssl/zlib
openssl
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
Openssl default config => /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
openssl.cafile => no value => no value
openssl.capath => no value => no value
Native OpenSSL support => enabled
```

If I try to open the file in terminal I get the same error:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in file.pfx -nodes
```

But if I use the `-legacy` param it works fine.

How can I use it in PHP without errors?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can enable legacy option for Openssl 3:

Find and open the file at `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`

At the `[default_sect]` section change it to the following:

```
[default_sect]
activate = 1
[legacy_sect]
activate = 1
```

Then find the `[provider_sect]` and change it to the following:

```
[provider_sect]
default = default_sect
legacy = legacy_sect
```

After this save the file and restart your PHP application and it should work fine.

Comment: I'm having the same issue right now. I tried this solution but it's not working. Has anyone actually did this and worked on their end?

Comment: I had to make one more change to openssl.cnf: comment in the line "providers = provider_sect" in the section "[openssl_init]". Then everything worked correctly.

Comment: Not the best solution long term, but allows one to at least continue functioning while rewriting their cert handlers in php to support openssl 3.

Answer (score 3):

You can handle [Marcelo's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73858615/4477336) in few commands (e.g. for Docker building image purpose):

```
sed -i '/^default = default_sect/a legacy = legacy_sect' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
sed -i '/^\[default_sect\]/a activate = 1' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
printf "[legacy_sect]\nactivate = 1" >> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

Btw. more info about default and legacy providers you can find on [the OpenSSL wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_3.0#Provider_implemented_digests)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, which was due to OpenSSL upgraded to version 3 in Ubuntu 22.04. The issue occured on Google Calendar API integration using P12 file.

I tried downgrading it to OpenSSL 1.1 (changing the app itself was not an option), but unsuccessfully.

At last the solution was to redeploy my app on a new server with Ubuntu 20.04... worked out of the box.

Comment: We updated to Ubuntu 22.04 as well and immediately ran into this issue (we were on 20.04 just fine). However the solution by Marcelo worked to get it working while we rewrite how we deal with certs in php. As leaving openssl with a legacy clause doesn't sound like the best of ideas long-term.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following config is in /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf:

```
[openssl_init]
providers = provider_sect
[provider_sect]
default = default_sect
legacy = legacy_sect
[default_sect]
activate = 1
[legacy_sect]
activate = 1
```